# Can't add many to one mapping in abstract class with inheritance type single using JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I am having an abstract class called Shape and three more sub classes called Circle, Triangle and Rectangle. I am using inheritance type single to map these classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shape")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "shape_type")
public abstract class Shape{
 public enum ShapeType {
        RECTANGLE,
        CIRCLE,
        TRIANGLE
    }

    @Column(name = "LENGTH")
    private String what;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "color_id")
    private Color color;

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    //getters and setters 

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "RECTANGLE")
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
//proerties
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CIRCLE")
public class Circle extends Shape {
//proerties
}
```

My problem is , when I add this getter method for attribute "color" I am getting an exception "**Failed to start bean documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.StackOverflowError**"

This is the full stack trace i am getting

```
 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176)
        at com.mvv.casat.SpringBootInitializer.main(SpringBootInitializer.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
    Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4830)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.CachingOperationReader.read(CachingOperationReader.java:57)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader.read(ApiDescriptionReader.java:66)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner.scan(ApiListingScanner.java:89)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDocumentationScanner.scan(ApiDocumentationScanner.java:71)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.scanDocumentation(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:95)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.any(Iterables.java:623)
        at springfox.documentation.schema.WildcardType.hasWildcards(WildcardType.java:42)
        at springfox.documentation.schema.WildcardType$1.apply(WildcardType.java:83)
        at springfox.documentation.schema.WildcardType$1.apply(WildcardType.java:80)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.indexOf(Iterators.java:778)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.any(Iterators.java:684)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.any(Iterables.java:623)
        at springfox.documentation.schema.WildcardType.hasWildcards(WildcardType.java:42)
        at springfox.documentation.schema.AlternateTypeRule.appliesTo(AlternateTypeRule.java:79)
        at springfox.documentation.spi.schema.AlternateTypeProvider$1.apply(AlternateTypeProvider.java:57)
        at springfox.documentation.spi.schema.AlternateTypeProvider$1.apply(AlternateTypeProvider.java:54)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:652)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.tryFind(Iterators.java:752)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.tryFind(Iterables.java:675)
        at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.firstMatch(FluentIterable.java:236)
        at springfox.documentation.spi.schema.AlternateTypeProvider.alternateFor(AlternateTypeProvider.java:41)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander.fieldType(ModelAttributeParameterExpander.java:256)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander.access$100(ModelAttributeParameterExpander.java:61)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander$9.apply(ModelAttributeParameterExpander.java:228)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander$9.apply(ModelAttributeParameterExpander.java:225)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
        at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:651)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:650)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander.expand(ModelAttributeParameterExpander.java:88)
```

Once I remove the getter method of color attribute it just works fine. I searched through internet but couldn't find an answer for this.
 Can any one help me to sort this?

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the stack trace of the exception. The problem is not in the JPA entity. It's in the code using it somehow. (note that your setter should be named setColor(), not Color()).

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my question.

Comment: So the error is in the springfox (which I assume is the tool that generates the swagger REST API documentation). It seems t have a bug (there is no valid reason for it to cause such an exception). That said, the fact that this error happens when you add a getter to an entity seems to imply that you're exposing this entity in your REST API, which could be a bad idea.

Comment: @JBNizet So, what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @JBNizet  I am using swagger to test the rest API. So, do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Except removing swagger, or changing the API to not expose this entity, no, not really.